# Best way to use Raknet from C#?

Tags: c#, raknet

I am trying to learn Raknet with C# and I found it extremely confusing.

The Raknet tutorial seems to work well in C++. I have already made the chat server from the tutorial.

I am looking to do something similar in C# but I'm having trouble.

- It seems that I need to compile Raknet using SWIG to have an interface to C#?
- I found a project called raknetdotnet but it seems to be abandoned...http://code.google.com/p/raknetdotnet/

So my main question is **what is the best way to use Raknet from C#?**

The following information would also be very helpful:

- A good tutorial for Raknet *and* C# together
- Sample C# code for Raknet

I've done a lot of research but I'm still stuck.

Maybe Raknet isn't what I need after all?  Comments with more C#-centric alternatives would also be appreciated.

Comment: From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raknet): _"RakNet is a C++ class library that provides TCP and reliable UDP transport."_ It's for C++, so you might well be on your own as far as .Net's managed C++ and C# go. If you're having this much difficulty, aren't there other TCP and UDP protocols you can use instead?

Comment: I was wondering about that in my PD. My supervisor adviced me to use raknet in C# but everything I read made me think maybe is not the best option...

Comment: Why not take a look at SuperSocket? It's written purely in C# and although I haven't used it personally (yet), I've heard just *so* many recommendations of it.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at SuperSocket :)
BTW I am wondering now who downvoted my question.. did I made something wrong?

Comment: Downvote plus 4 votes to close, but no comments explaining why?

Comment: It will be nice to know why.. not for my ego, just to avoid making same mistake twice :)
Anyway this really worked for me as Astyanax gave me good info!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything you need can, more or less, be found on the official site,

- **raknet.com/raknet/manual/**

There, they also have an official tutorial for using RakNet in C#, which is based on SWIG (just like raknetdotnet):

- **jenkinssoftware.com/raknet/manual/swigtutorial.html**

You may be interested in lidgren, which is written in C#:

- https://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

A basic but complete tutorial for starters can be found here:

- http://www.mmo2play.com/?page=tutorials&tut=rnb

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for mentioning Lidgren.  It's a great networking engine.

Comment: Thanks. I have been googling a lot and I think I suffer overinformation. So many info about C++ hides good resources in C#.

I will make a depth read on this links. I have already read about swig and found it a little bit confusing.

Comment: +1 I am testing Lidgren right now and seems very cool. Thanks!